# Limit of Hermite polynomials $H_n (x)$ for $x\ll 1$

Tags: polynomials

Is there a formula for
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n (x)$$ in the limit $x\ll1$, where $H_n(x)$ is the Hermitian polynomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[We know that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Explicit_expression)
$$
H_{2n}(0)=\frac{4^n \sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(1/2 - n)}
$$
and
$$
H_{2n+1}(0)=0
$$
which means
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^n \sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(1/2 - n)}=\infty
$$
i.e., the sum diverges.

Comment: Could you explain where you are getting that $H_{2n+1}(0)=0$ from?

Comment: @supercoolphysicist sure. In the link ("we know that") you can see the explicit form of $H_n(x)$. Look at the second expression, valid for **odd** $n$. In this expression, you can see that $H_n(x)=\sum_\ell c_\ell (2x)^{2\ell+1}$, which is zero for $x=0$. Also, in the same link, in the section [special values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Special_Values) you can see that $H_n(0)=0$ for odd $n$.